# Count likes button like in the demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

Can someone please tell me how can I create a heart button like in  [this demo blog](http://uno.thebasicpage.com/.)?

And how to count likes on mouse click, not mouse hover?

Comment: you can get this like button in https://design.google.com/icons/

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML

```
<div class="tbp-hrt-container">
    <div class="tbp-hrt finish" href="http://uno.thebasicpage.com/2016/01/home-office.html" data-id="1"></div> 71
</div>
```

In your CSS file

```
@import http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css;


.tbp-hrt-container {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
}

.tbp-hrt {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 13px!important;
}

.tbp-hrt.finish:before {
    color: #e65a47;
    content: "\f004";
    font-weight: 400!important;
    font-family: fontawesome;
}

.tbp-hrt.finish:after {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400!important;
}
.tbp-hrt:after {
    content: attr(data-amount) "";
    font: normal normal 11px Martel Sans, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The number of likes on mouse hover is acquired with jQuery (I think) and the _finish_ class appears only when you hover over the heart button. What I wanted to know is how to count likes on mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fontawsome which contains complete set of 634 icons(http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" id="heart" onClick="like()"></i>
```

and use javascript for the mouse click event

js

```
var likeCount = 10;

function like(){
    likeCount++;
}
```

You should use font-awsomes than images to reduce your sites size because font-awsomes are just like fonts.